# PostgreSQL Recursive CTE - Return Empty if false value found

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using a recursive query, I'm querying for all ancestors of a field using a `parent` id field. If a `false` value is found in the `enabled` field for any ancestor, then the query should return empty rows.

Say I have the following table called `my_table`

| Field | Type |
| --- | --- |
| id | integer |
| parent | integer |
| enabled | boolean |

It's populated with the following data:

| id | parent | enabled |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | true |
| 2 | 1 | true |
| 3 | 1 | true |
| 4 | 2 | true |

I have the following recursive query:

```
WITH recursive my_rec AS
(
    SELECT id, parent, enabled
    FROM my_table
    WHERE id = 4
    
    UNION ALL

    SELECT t.id, t.parent, t.enabled
    FROM my_table t
    INNER JOIN my_rec
    ON t.id = my_rec.parent
)

SELECT *
FROM my_rec
```

For `id = 4` this correctly returns

| id | parent | enabled |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2 | true |
| 2 | 1 | true |
| 1 | null | true |

But say I were to update `id` `2` so that it's changed from `enabled` `true` to `false`.
Example:

| id | parent | enabled |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | true |
| 2 | 1 | false |
| 3 | 1 | true |
| 4 | 2 | true |

Now I want my query to return for `id = 4` nothing. This is because in the "ancestry" tree of `id` `4`, `enabled` is `false` for `id` `2`.

How can I update my query above to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can try to use `NOT EXISTS` subquery to
judge cte if any `enabled` is false didn't show anything as your expect, otherwise show all of them.

```
WITH recursive my_rec AS
(
    SELECT id, parent, enabled
    FROM my_table
    WHERE id = 4
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.id, t.parent, t.enabled
    FROM my_table t
    INNER JOIN my_rec
    ON t.id = my_rec.parent
)
SELECT *
FROM my_rec
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM my_rec
   WHERE enabled = false
)
```

or we can use `COUNT` condition aggregate function to make it, getting `false_cnt` and judgement.

```
WITH recursive my_rec AS
(
    SELECT id, parent, enabled
    FROM my_table
    WHERE id = 4
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.id, t.parent, t.enabled
    FROM my_table t
    INNER JOIN my_rec
    ON t.id = my_rec.parent
)
SELECT *
FROM (
 SELECT *,COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE enabled = false) OVER() false_cnt
 FROM my_rec
) t1
WHERE false_cnt = 0
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=267e6131eed98debdb8218adb2224fed)

Comment: Thanks! The first query is exactly what I was looking for!